# React native cutting egde

Tags: react-native

I want to obtain this layout but was not able to find any good solution.
Just want to know how can i have that cutting edge on bottom left corner, I have already tried rotate property.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5fO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `[React-native-svg][1]` for angles on images or clip path creation.
You can use regular styles for those circle buttons.
If there is animations, you need `animated` or `react-native-reanimated` and `react-native-gesture-handler`.
[1]: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg